# Fundamental solution of a second order differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Consider the differential operator
$$
L=u''-u\qquad \mathrm{in}\ \ \mathbb{R}.
$$
Find the fundamental solution of the above operator.

Now, I guessed the fundamental solution to be $E=e^{x}H(x)$, where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function. But, after finding its second weak derivative (in distribution sense), I get it as
$$
E+\delta-\delta'
$$
where $\delta'$ is the dipole distribution and $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution. But this doesn't satisfy the operator, $L$. My question is am I taking the guess solution correctly? If not what should it be and how to think about getting these guess solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental solution $G$ should satisfy

1. $LG=0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,\infty)$,
2. boundary conditions, usually $\lim_{R\to \infty} G(\pm R)=0$,
3. be continuous, so $G(0+)=G(0-)$,
4. $G'(0+)-G'(0-)=1$ (to make $LG=\delta$).

For $Lu=u''-u$ conditions 1 and 2 give
$$
G(x)=\begin{cases}
A_- e^x & (x<0),\\
A_+ e^{-x} & (x>0).
\end{cases}
$$

Then conditions 3 and 4 give $A_- = A_+$ and $-A_+ - A_-=1,$ i.e. $A_-=A_+=-\frac12$
so we end up with
$$
G(x) = -\frac12 e^{-|x|}.
$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann. True. Will edit my answer.

Comment: It should be $A_-=A_+ = -1/2$, and our answers will coincide ;)

Comment: @LL3.14. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A fast way to solve $u''-u=\delta_0$ is to take the Fourier transform to get $(-|2π y|^2-1)\,\mathcal F(u)(y) = 1$, and so
$$
u(x) = \mathcal F^{-1}\!\,\left(\frac{-1}{1+|2π x|^2} \right) = -\frac{e^{-|x|}}{2}.
$$